$|\int f'(x) \mu(dx)| \leq (\int f^2 dx)^{1/2} \implies \mu$ is ac. wrt. Lebesgue measure
Question: If $\mu$ is a measure on $[0,1]$ with the Borel $\sigma-$algebra, such that    $|\int f'(x) \mu(dx)| \leq (\int f^2 dx)^{1/2}$ for all $f$ continuously differentiable, show that $\mu << m|_{[0,1]}$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.
Attempt: I hoped to show this directly, so assuming $m(A) = 0$, I want to show $\mu(A)=0$. Now, I want to extend the above inequality to $\chi_A$ via a density argument, because then, if $\int_0^x \chi_A(s) ds =: F(s)$, then it is differentiable $m$-almost everywhere by the Lebesgue different theorem, and we have (formally defining $F'(x) := c$ if the derivative doesn't exist):
Q1) Assuming the above inequality holds for $\chi_A$, is the following correct?
$\mu(A \cap \{ F' \text{ exists} \}) + c \mu\{ F' \text{ doesn't exist} \}) = \int_0^1 F'(x) d\mu(x)$ $ \leq (\int_0^1 F^2 dx)^{1/2} \leq \int_0^1 \int_a^x \chi_A(s) ds dx =0 $, since the integrand is $0$ $m$-almost everywhere, which implies that $\mu(A) = 0$.
Q2) Difficulties in the density argument
If the above is right, here is my difficulty in the density argument: I know that polynomials on $[0,1] - R[x] - $ is dense in $C([0,1])$ wrt. the $L^{\infty}$ norm, and $C([0,1])$ is dense in $L^1(0,1)$ wrt. the $L^1$-norm, and since $L^{\infty} \subset L^1$, so that convergence in the former implies that in the latter on compact spaces, we have $R[x]$ dense in $L^1(0,1)$.
But then, if I approximate $f'$ by some $g' \in R[x]$, so that I get information on the RHS of the inequality, then I get no information about $f$ being approximated by $g$, so that I cannot say anything about the RHS of the above inequality. Thus, I think a density argument won't work here, but I'm not sure what else to try.

A better approach is to consider the map $Tf=\int f'(x)d\mu(x)$ an use Riesz Theorem for the Hilbert space $L^{2}[0,1]$.

Thank you @geetha290krm, I'll try that out! Although the book I'm studying this from hasn't yet covered Riesz Theorem, so while this might be a "better approach", there might also be an approach relying on 'less heavy machinery'?

Edit: In your argument, if $m(A)=0$ then the function $F(x) = \int_0^x1_A(t)dt = 0$ everywhere and hence $F'(x)=0$ identically, so it doesn't work since $\int F'd\mu \neq \int_A \mu$.
Maybe you can use the following estimate if not the suggestion from the comment:
$$ \int_0^1f(x)^2dx = \int_0^1 \left(\int^x_0f'(t)dt\right)^2dx \leq \int_0^1 \left(\int^x_0(f'(t))^2dt \right)dx   \leq  \int_0^1 f'(t)^2dt$$
for $f$ such that $f(0)=0$ and then follow by a density argument. For any compact set $K$ of $[0,1]$, chose $f_n$ such that
$$ f'_n(x) = (1-nd(x,K))_+, \quad f_n(x) = \int_0^x f'_n(t)dt,$$
where $d(x,K) = \inf_{y\in K}|x-y|$. Next, note that
$$ \forall x \in [0,1], \quad 1_K(x) \leq f'_n(x) \leq 1_{K^{1/n}}(x),$$
where $K^\epsilon = \{ x \in[0,1]: d(x,K)<\epsilon  \}$ and thus $f'_n(x) \rightarrow 1_K(x) $ pointwise (note that $f'_n$ is continuous for each $n$). By Fatou lemma and DCT, we have
$$\mu(K) \leq \liminf \Big|\int f_n'(x) d\mu(x) \Big| \leq \lim_n \left(\int_0^1 f'_n(t)^2dt\right)^{1/2}  = m(K)^{1/2}. $$
Since both measures are regular, we must have $\mu(A)\leq m(A)^{1/2}$ for any $A$. In particular, if $m(A)=0$ then $\mu(A)=0$, which means $\mu$ is absolute continuous w.r.t Lebesgue measure $m$.

Thank you very much!!
